# CoordinatorLayout Toolbar invisible on enter until full height

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout

Included in my *activity_main.xml*'s `DrawerLayout` is a `CoordinatorLayout` called *content_layout.xml*. Within this `CoordinatorLayout` is my `AppBarLayout` containing a `Toolbar`, then a `LinearLayout` for a fragment's content.

When a fragment containing a `RecyclerView` is scrolled up, the toolbar exits successfully. The problem lies when scrolling down to bring the toolbar back. The toolbar does not appear until the full height of the toolbar has been scrolled and as such leaves an unsightly white box in its place as shown.

[image: toolbar]

*content_layout.xml*

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <!-- The main content view for fragments-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The toolbar is initialized via `MainActivity`'s `onCreate()`:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

I would appreciate any suggestions as to resolving this. Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I was having this same issue and the only thing I found that solved it was by having something else other than the `toolbar` inside the `AppBarLayout`. I placed an invisible view in my layout underneath the toolbar. Not the most ideal solution, but it worked.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">      

     <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

     <View
        android:id="@+id/appbar_bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: That's brilliant, thanks! Works great. Though, like you, I'm not entirely sure why.

Comment: Awesome thx for this.

You can also put height to be 0.1dp so it wont be visible at all (well almost at all ;) )

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jon Cordeiro