# AppBarLayout - Layout sometimes invisible once it enters view (even if it's not entered)

Tags: android, material-design, android-design-library, android-appbarlayout

I have a problem where sometimes the AppBarLayout will not show its full content all the time when you play around with it:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="148dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:background="@color/primarycolor"
                .../>

        <RelativeLayout
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                ...>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

A solution provided is

[CoordinatorLayout Toolbar invisible on enter until full height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30895579/coordinatorlayout-toolbar-invisible-on-enter-until-full-height/30900102#30900102)

BUT: it provides a full line  that is not the same color as the primary color I specify in the bottom layout, because its background is white. Thoughts?

Comment: bug report (fixed in support lib 23.4.0): https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=178037

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution extending the one provided above:
Use this instead of the one provided, which will blend the appbarlayout and the subtle shadow elevation below it.

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/appbar_bottom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height=".3dp"
    android:background="#606060"
    android:visibility="visible"/>
```

and the resultant layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="148.3dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:background="@color/primarycolor"
            .../>

    <RelativeLayout
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            ...>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/appbar_bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height=".3dp"
        android:background="#606060"
        android:visibility="visible"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: This bug was fixed in the recently released support library version 23.4.0: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=178037