# CoordinatorLayout - View disappears after RecyclerView item click

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout

Title says it all.  The search view in this layout hides behind the toolbar and looks great.

The top level toolbar is the one supplied to the support actionbar
The search view toolbar is just used as a view

The last item in the recyclerview loads more results and calls 'notifyItemRangeInserted'.  Once you do that, the toolbar shadow disappears and when you scroll up, the search view is completely blank.

Any ideas why?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:actionBarSize" />

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?android:listPreferredItemHeight"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/search_bar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:background="@drawable/search_background"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
                app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
                app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
                app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/search_icon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:paddingBottom="9dp"
                    android:paddingEnd="12dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="13dp"
                    android:paddingRight="12dp"
                    android:paddingStart="13dp"
                    android:paddingTop="9dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/search_icon" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/search_text"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/transparent"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                    android:fontFamily="@string/roboto_light"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:hint="@string/action_search"
                    android:imeOptions="actionGo"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:minLines="1"
                    android:paddingBottom="9dp"
                    android:paddingTop="9dp"
                    android:textColor="#666666"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/search_results"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:paddingBottom="?android:listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
            android:paddingTop="4dp"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/search_results_count"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?android:listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@color/light_gray"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/medium_grey"
            tools:text="results results" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Place the Toolbar inside AppBarLayout... wait! You have two of them!

Comment: yeah... 1 is the toolbar supplied to the actionbar.  The other is a toolbar view with an imageview and edittext that gets pushed up/down on scroll.  I couldn't get the functionality with a linear layout as the search parent but it works with toolbar

Comment: well that's a functionality I've never heard of before. Why not put that in a LinearLayout?

Comment: answered that before you even asked it, lol.  see above :)

Comment: side note:  even if the search view parent is changed from toolbar to linear layout... it still disappears

Comment: Can you post your Activity code as well ?

Comment: closing this issue.  Turns out it's a known bug (https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=178037).  Solution can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31084658/appbarlayout-layout-sometimes-invisible-once-it-enters-view-even-if-its-not?rq=1